# How to get the trait name with namespace inside itself?

Tags: php, namespaces, traits

I want to know if there is a way to get the traits namespace inside itself, I know that I can use `self::class` to get the classname, but inside a trait it gets the namespace of the class that is using the trait, I don't want to type it's name fixed like `new ReflectionClass('trait')`

Is there any function or const that can do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm a little bit confused by your question but if you need the fully qualified name from the trait then you may use `__TRAIT__` magic constant and if you only need the namespace of the trait then you may use `__NAMESPACE__`. For example, declare a trait using a namespace:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Traits;

trait Methods
{
    public function getNamespace()
    {
        // Get fully qualified name of the trait
        echo __TRAIT__; // App\Http\Controllers\Traits\Methods

        echo PHP_EOL;

        // Get namespace of the trait
        echo __NAMESPACE__; // App\Http\Controllers\Traits
    }
}
```

Now, declare a class using another namespace and use that trait inside this class:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Traits\Methods;

class TraitController
{
    use Methods;

    public function index()
    {
        // Call the method declared in trait
        $this->getNamespace();
    }
}


(new TraitController)->index();
```

The predefined [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__TRAIT__` (since 5.4.0) and `__NAMESPACE__` (since 5.3.0) is used so use which one is needed. Tested in `php v-5.4.0`. Check the demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/566de20dd95e105bed9c82760d89ecc5f58d7b46).

Also, if you want to get the fully qualified name of the trait from the class that is using it then you may use `NameOfTheTrait::class` (`NameOfTheClass::class`/`NameOfTheInterface::class`) but this is available since `php v-5.5`.

Also be careful when using `self::class`. The `self::class` will give the fully qualified name of the class where you've used it because the `self` always references the lexical scope (where it's physically used) since the scope of `self` is determined during the compile time so you may get unexpected results if you inherit a class where a `self::class` statement is used. In other words, if you call any static method from a child class then the calling context will be still the parent class if you use `self` in your parent class, in that case you need to use `static` instead of `self`. This is actually another topic so please read more on php manual about [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).